# How to get pixel size of Data Frame in arcMap layout?

Tags: arcmap, c#, layouts

[image: Data Frame]

The data frame where the map diagram will be presented in, appeared on the screen not in the actual size which is part of A4 page template, I want to get the actual size by getting the pixel size and convert it to centimeters.

How to get the pixel size of Data Frame?

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the data frame --> Propreties --> Size and Position
On the right, you will find the size of your data frame (by default in inches).

The converstion to centimeters can be done in the main menu of ArcMap: File --> Page and Print Setup (change the Map Page Size units to cm)

Comment: i want to get the pixel size by code.

Comment: ok, then you can allways call the data frame class: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000003000000